# Change the actually displayed EOL symbol in notepad++ to ¬

Tags: notepad++

So, when I show EOL characters I get this ugly bulky symbol, I'd like to change this somehow, prefferably to ¬

And not (LF) or (CR), but something less disturbing and distracting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Download Notepad++ source code.

If you find the symbol `ControlCharacterString`
in file `<notepad++ source root>\scintilla\src\Editor.cxx`, you will see array of all those symbols there ("NUL", "SOH", ... ,"CR", ... and so on...)

If you replace them as you wish and build Notepad++ from these sources again, then you will get this changed. However, the symbol will remain in inverted rounded shape. Changing this would need more code changes.